Last day of a multi index dataframe
Having a multi index dataframe of 3 levels (year, month and day) I want to keep the last day of every month, in the case below, on april 2024, only day 4 should be kept


Found the solution:
dfx.groupby(level=[0,1]).last()


In the future, please post your code and data, rather than an image!
See also here.
Let me first recreate a minimal working DataFrame for your problem.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

years = range(2023, 2025)
months = range(1, 4)
days = range(3)

YEAR, MONTH, DAY = "year", "month", "day"

d = {(year, month, day): (np.random.randint(0, 100),) 
        for year in years for month in months for day in days}
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=d,
    columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys(), names=(YEAR, MONTH, DAY)
)).T

Now, I get the numeric values of all days and sort this by the largest for each combination of year and month. The "ugly" conversion from pd.Series to pd.DataFrame is needed to have access to the correct groupby method.
maxdays = pd.DataFrame(data=df.index.get_level_values(DAY), index=df.index).groupby(level=(YEAR, MONTH)).apply(max)

Finally, I get the relevant indices and use these to slice the original data.
idxs = maxdays.set_index(maxdays.to_numpy().flatten(), append=True).index
last_day_of_each_month = df.loc[idxs]
print(last_day_of_each_month)


too complex, solution is much easier. dfx.groupby(level=[0,1]).last()
